# How do I reiterate through a pointer array?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, pointers

My program is supposed to iterate through an array for as many times as there are hours using only a pointer.

```
for (int i = 0; i < totalHours; i++)
{
    cout << " " << i + 1;
    while (ptrSvr <= last)
    {
        rand_set(ptrSvr);
        print(ptrSvr);
        ptrSvr++;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

return 0;
```

With this being the function for rand_set

```
void rand_set(int* &ps)
{
    *ps = rand() % 10;
}
```

And this being the function for print.

```
 void print(int* ps)
 {
     cout << "       " << *ps << " ";
 }
```

Once this iterates though, I don't understand how to set the pointer back to the first address in the array so that when i increases, it will print a new row starting at the beginning. Currently, it will only print one row. There's also a catch - I can only use the given pointer to access the array. I cannot use array indices.

Additionally, the highest number randomly generated must be stored in a highestAttempts pointer and when printed, must have a * next to it. This functionality must be included in the rand_set function. I've only gotten it to print a * next to all of them, or it gets printed on the first random number, and on each one if they increase.

Thanks for any advice in advance. I am in a 200 level c++ class, so this should be as simple as possible.

Variables are declared and initialized like so.

```
void initialize(int ts, int* &ps, int* &pt,
                int* &l, int* &ha)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ts; i++)
    {
        ps[i] = 0;
        pt[i] = 0;
        l = &ps[i];
    }

    ha = NULL;
    srand(time(NULL));
}
```

...

```
// Pointer declarations          
int *ptrSvr;                // Po
int *ptrTotal;              // Po
int *last;                  // Po
int *highestAttempts;       // Po

// Variable declarations         
int totalServers;           // Va
int totalHours;             // Va
int total;                  // Va

// Prompt user for number of serv
// totalServers and totalHours   
cout << "Enter the number of web 
cin >> totalServers;             
cout << "Enter the number of hour
cin >> totalHours;               

// Declares arrays for ptrSvr and
// of total servers              
ptrSvr = new int[totalServers];  
ptrTotal = new int[totalServers];
```

Comment: code does not have enough context. How do you set value of `ptrSvr` and `last`. Depending on that there are different approaches.

Comment: @MarekR I added the rest of the context.

Comment: Are you sure you are in a C++ class? It looks more like you are learning C with only `printf` and `malloc` replaced by `cout` and `new`.  Anyway, please provide an actual [mcve], i.e., something that can be copied and compiled directly.

Answer (score -1):

if you have something like

int arr [] = {};

then

```
ptrSvr = arr;
```

after `while` loop would reset it. otherwise you have to store the very first value of `ptrSvr` and reset it after `while` loop exits